# Regular expression for tokenization in java

Tags: java, tokenize, data-retrieval

All
I'm trying to do tokenization for the following text

```
"I am a cat, Cat Cat ah. Are you a C.A.T?"
```

But I have to follow the rules:

1.Two or more words separated by whitespace, all of which begin with a capital letter, must be preserved as a single token.

2.Acronym should be preserved as a single token with or without full stop or period (e.g. C.A.T can result in CAT or C.A.T).

The correct output should be like this: `I, am, a, cat, Cat Cat, Are, you, C.A.T.`

I just wonder how to write regular expressions to represent the scenarios if I wanna use Matcher in java to do the work?

Comment: what about "ah." ? would that also be tokenized? with or without the "."

Comment: Hi, Sharma! At this stage, just ignore that:)

Comment: `\b(?:\p{Lu}(?:\.\p{Lu})+|\p{Lu}\p{L}*(?:\s+\p{Lu}\p{L}*)+|\p{L}+)\b`. See [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/3IMVh8/1) for demo.

Comment: I have tested \\b(([A-Z]\\S+))\\b. But it only returned all the words beginning with a capital letter. What I need is words which begin with capital into one token.